# Rails + AJAX: Spinner doesn't show up when is started AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, spinner

I have a form for searching purposes. This form is "AJAX-ed" and it's working well.
Now I am trying to add the spinner functionality, like this:

#### index.html.haml

```
#spinner{:style => 'display: none;'} LOADING...  
= render 'articles/show_data'
```

#### search.js.erb

```
$("#search_form")
    .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(){
      alert('xx');
      //$("#spinner").show();
    })
    .bind("ajax:complete", function(){
      $("#spinner").hide();
    })
$('.show_articles').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: '/articles/show_data')) %>");
```

Data are printed out correctly, the problem is, that when I send the form, the spinner is not displayed. (the ID element of the form is really called **search_form**)

Where should be placed the code for displaying and hiding spinner? I've tried to put into a separate file, also to the JS file where are rendered data through AJAX (the snipper above), but none of that has worked for me.

I am using jQuery 1.9.

I would be grateful for helping me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Does your alert show up?

Comment: Where is the html for rendering the spinner?

Comment: Are you using `async: false`?

Comment: @Jason - no, it doesn't. That's the problem.

Comment: @Pinny in the file called **index.html.haml**.

Comment: What does your rendered output look like?

Comment: @kevin no, sorry, but where it should be used? (I've never used it before).

Comment: @user984621 It shouldn't be used. If it were used, it could cause the symptoms you are seeing./

Comment: First of all, using js.erb files it's a really bad idea. You're messing with 3 languages in there and it's very hard to debug as you can see. You try to set global `beforeSend` callback after you make the ajax call. It will never work. You need to set those callbacks globally.

Answer (score 1):

To the commenters: there's nothing wrong with using `.js.erb`. However, OP obviously doesn't understand how it fits in to the notion of request/response.

The form is submitted, Rails routes the submission to your controller and action. Your controller action then does whatever it does, and responds with `search.js.erb` and the browser executes this as javascript when it receives it. So, this means that you're not telling `#search_form` about its `beforeSend` hook until after the form has been sent.

TLDR; Move your `$('#search_form')..` code into a JS asset file that gets loaded with the page.

oh, and uncomment the line that actually shows the spinner...

Oh and finally, there's about 4 million pages/posts about AJAX spinners, do a little search one in a while.

Comment: Dude, at first - regarding to uncommenting line with spinner - take a look rather at the HAML syntax. At second - do you really think that the first thing what I did was to post a question here???

Comment: Did you read the rest of my post? Move the javascript that defines the AJAX hooks into a JS file that gets loaded with the page. And yes, I do think that the first thing you did was post here, because about 90% of your 400 or so questions could all be answered by googling or reading the guides.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, do you have `remote: true`? Try ajax:before rather than beforeSend:

```
$("#search_form")
.bind("ajax:before", function(){
  alert('xx');
  //$("#spinner").show();
})
...
```

That works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, yes, I use `remote: true` in the form, but it still doesn't work for me. Check out my answer to the topic how I solved it, it's probably not the best solution, but it's working...

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't able to fix this within more than 2 hours, I solved this issue in the following way:

#### custom_js.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_submit_input").click(function(){
    $('#spinner').show();
  });
});
```

This will display the spinner when the form is submitted.

Afterwards, in **search.js.erb**

```
$('.show_articles').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: '/articles/show_data')) %>");
$('#spinner').hide();
```

when to content from database is rendered, then hide the spinner.
It's probably not the cleanest way to handle spinner, but it's the working solution.